# Run VBS script for multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a VBS macro for every .xlsx file in a folder.
The macro would delete all name ranges in each file.

I have tested and have working code which deletes all nameranges.
ALT + F11 and then inserting a module and hitting F5 to run it,
however I want this automated and run for every file in a folder without having to open the xlsx file.

```
Dim RangeName As Name


On Error Resume Next
For Each RangeName In Names
    ActiveWorkbook.Names(RangeName.Name).Delete
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: You can't change the contents of *any* file without opening it.  You can open Excel files with other programs (XML, Visual Studio, etc) but you would still have to open then save them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Path, Filename As String
Dim nName As Name

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Path = "" 'FolderPath
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx") 'xlsx, xls etc.

Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True

    For Each nName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        nName.Delete
    Next nName

    Workbooks(Filename).Close savechanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()

Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```